# Splitting of polygons and spatial join of lines to polygons in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-join

For the past couple of weeks I have been arduously creating flood depth rasters using flood zone polygons  and base flood elevation survey lines.

[image: img]

The issue is that some of the zones do not have a base flood elevation assigned. So far, I've just been using the lines to split the polygons and roughly shifting the lines a small distance diagonally, all at once, to perform a spatial join to the polygons. The lines are shifted because they are of course being used to split the polygons and are overlapping the splits. I then manually go through null values that resulted from a bad spatial join and manually change those.

So far, this is what I have been doing and everyone is satisfied with the result. It has proven accurate. The polygons are then used to create a raster.

Is there an easier way to do this? Not necessarily looking for a script.